# Replace dictionaries keys with values from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
keys = ['id', 'name', 'address']

list = [{'Value': 1}, {'Value': 'Example name'}, {'VarCharValue': 'GA'}]
```

Looking for the most pythonic way to replace key dicts keys. I tried with for loop and list indexes but it was ugly. Excepted result:

```
list = [{'id': 1}, {'name': 'Example name'}, {'address': 'GA'}]
```

Comment: Side note, don't shadow built-ins, use `lst` or `list_` or `L` instead of `list` for your variable name.

Comment: `[{k: list(d.values()).pop()} for k, d in zip(keys, lst)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `zip`. To extract the only value in a dictionary `d`, you can use `next(iter(d.values()))` or `list(d.values())[0]`.

```
K = ['id', 'name', 'address']

L = [{'Value': 1}, {'Value': 'Example name'}, {'VarCharValue': 'GA'}]

res = [{k: next(iter(v.values()))} for k, v in zip(K, L)]

[{'id': 1}, {'name': 'Example name'}, {'address': 'GA'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use iter(), you can use list(), which looks almost the same as jpp's solution

`res = [{k: list(v.values())[0]} for k,v in zip(K,L)]`

In this, you simply convert the dict_values object to a list, and get the first item, instead of getting the iterator and calling next on it.